# How can i replace all Zeros with NA if there are at least two zeros after each other in a column?

Tags: r, replace

I got daily Price/Return data from Datastream. Since Datastream doesn't end a series if a stock is dead, it shows the last valid Price until the end of my time span. I want to replace all these Zero Returns by NA. But by doing this, i might change some valid Zero returns. So i want to replace Zeros by NA only if there are two (or 4, have to specify) Zeros after each other. Since i'm new to r im not familiar with if conditions/loops.

This was my first try:

```
Return.Monthly[Return.Monthly==0]<-NA
```

but as i said there are some valid Returns that might be deleted.

So i want like:

```
  Return.Monthly[Return.Monthly==0]<-NA if (Return.Monthly[i+1,]     ==0)
```

Of course this would have to work for the last row as well. (In the best case)

Thank you very much for your help !

**EDIT:**

So Now i got this:

Returns:

```
       AAPL  AMZ    YHOO
        0.2   0.3     0
        0     0      0.4
        0     0.3    0.6
        0     0.2    0.5
```

And i want this :

Returns:

```
       AAPL    AMZ    YHOO
        0.2    0.3     0
        NA     0       0.4
        NA     0.3     0.6
        NA     0.2     5
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data which explains what "if there are two Zeros after each other" means?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the request. My description wasn't accurate.

Comment: Can you also add column headers so we know what each column is?

Comment: Yes of course, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all companies exist in the first period and no company disappears in the last period:

```
 ret <- rbind(c(0.2, 0.3, 0),
              c(0, 0, 0.4),
              c(0, 0.3, 0.6),
             c(0, 0.2, 0.5))

retU <- rbind(ret[-1,], 0L) # shifts the matrix up one row to
                                     # compare with the next period 
both <- (ret == 0) & (retU == 0)

retcpy = ret
retcpy[cbind(row(ret)[both], col(ret)[both])] <- NA


> ret 
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.2  0.3  0.0
[2,]  0.0  0.0  0.4
[3,]  0.0  0.3  0.6
[4,]  0.0  0.2  0.5
> retcpy
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.2  0.3  0.0
[2,]   NA  0.0  0.4
[3,]   NA  0.3  0.6
[4,]   NA  0.2  0.5
```